# Paid Membership Pro php function to hide ads displays on frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Been trying different methods to get this to work and function. PmPro for wordpress has a function to Hide Ads for Member Specific levels. The code they give is this:

> To hide ads in your template code, use code like the following:
>
> if ( function_exists( 'pmpro_displayAds' ) && pmpro_displayAds() ) {
> //insert ad code here }

So, if I add my ad code it works perfect HOWEVER, this displays on the frontend:

"if ( function_exists( 'pmpro_displayAds' ) && pmpro_displayAds()"

No matter where I add the code. Have tried the footer, header, page specific and same result. Just shows on the front but works.

I have tried the php include file function to include a php file with the ad code... doesnt work.
have tried various other methods and have searched for hours. I cannot solve this.

Basically.... how can I add:

> if ( function_exists( 'pmpro_displayAds' ) && pmpro_displayAds() ) {
> //insert ad code here }

without if ( function_exists( 'pmpro_displayAds' ) && pmpro_displayAds() displaying on the front?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. It's been solved in this thread:
[How to wrap <script> into if statement for wordpress <head>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66120073/how-to-wrap-script-into-if-statement-for-wordpress-head)

I added the snippet to the header.php