# How to wrap <script> into if statement for wordpress <head>

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I've been trying to implement a code provided by a wordpress plugin maker and I need a bit of help confirming if it works or not.
The plugin in question is the PaidMembership Pro and it provides a possibility to hide ads for members.
This is the snippet of code I should add to the template:

```
if ( function_exists( 'pmpro_displayAds' ) && pmpro_displayAds() ) {
    //insert ad code here
}
```

The ad code is a simply google adsense code:

```
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-111111111111111" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

I have no idea how to do it right. I tried adding it like this to wordpress header.php but wordpress throws me an error.

```
<?php if ( function_exists( 'pmpro_displayAds' ) && pmpro_displayAds() ) {
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-111111111111111" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
} ?>
```

I tried a couple of other variations too but didn't seem to work. Could someone help me out at least pointing me to a direction where I can look for answers? How the if should be wrapped or should it be at all? If I don't wrap it at all, it just shows up on the top of the frontend.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed HTML and PHP code in your try.
To make PHP generate the HTML you wish, you have to echo it:

```php
<?php
if ( function_exists( 'pmpro_displayAds' ) && pmpro_displayAds() ) {
  echo('<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-111111111111111" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>');
}
?>
```

for more on this, see [`echo()` in PHP-Manuals](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

All PHP-Code (e.g. wordpress-logic) has to be wrapped in `<?php ?>` in order to get executed by the webserver.

Comment: Yeah, I was just shooting in the dark. It works as it should now, thanks a lot!